# Not able to understand some lines of the code written in basic javascript. Please explain

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I understand the part upto the object 'Character' being made. But when we make a prototype object 'Player', i dont get concept behind this

```
Player.initPlayer = function(name, health, force){......}
```

- What is this '.initPlayer' ?
- And this function without any name, is their any alternative for definig this     function ?
- Like that there are more functions without any name and are just assigned to Player's object like - Player.describe=function(), What is 'fight' in this line ?

The actual code is at the bottom of the page of this link: https://openclassrooms.com/courses/learn-the-basics-of-javascript/understand-object-oriented-programming

Under the last topic of this page, Under the heading: 'Next Level:make a game!'

I will also copy the code here.

```
var Character = {
    // Initialize the character
    initCharacter: function (name, health, force) {
        this.name = name;
        this.health = health;
        this.force = force;
    },
    // Attack a target
    attack: function (target) {
        if (this.health > 0) {
            var damage = this.force;
            console.log(this.name + " attacks " + target.name + " and causes " + damage + " damage points");
            target.health = target.health - damage;
            if (target.health > 0) {
                console.log(target.name + " has " + target.health + " health points left");
            } else {
                target.health = 0;
                console.log(target.name + " has been eliminated!");
            }
        } else {
            console.log(this.name + " can't attack (they've been eliminated).");
        }
    }
};

var Player = Object.create(Character);
// Initialize the player
Player.initPlayer = function (name, health, force) {
    this.initCharacter(name, health, force);
    this.xp = 0;
};
// Describe the player
Player.describe = function () {
    var description = this.name + " has " + this.health + " health points, " +
        this.force + " force points " + this.xp + " experience points";
    return description;
};
// Fight an enemy
Player.fight = function (enemy) {
    this.attack(enemy);
    if (enemy.health === 0) {
        console.log(this.name + " eliminated " + enemy.name + " and wins " +
            enemy.value + " experience points");
        this.xp += enemy.value;
    }
};

var Enemy = Object.create(Character);
// Initialize the enemy
Enemy.initEnemy = function (name, health, force, species, value) {
    this.initCharacter(name, health, force);
    this.species = species;
    this.value = value;
};

// ...
```

Then the method calls for running the above code

```
// ...

var player1 = Object.create(Player);
player1.initPlayer("Rainbow Dash", 150, 25);

var player2 = Object.create(Player);
player2.initPlayer("Applejack", 130, 30);

console.log("Welcome to the adventure! Here are our heros:");
console.log(player1.describe());
console.log(player2.describe());

var monster = Object.create(Enemy);
monster.initEnemy("Spike", 40, 20, "orc", 10);

console.log("A wild monster has appeared: it's a(n) " + monster.species + " named " + monster.name);

monster.attack(player1);
monster.attack(player2);

player1.fight(monster);
player2.fight(monster);

console.log(player1.describe());
console.log(player2.describe());
```

Please explain. I do get the argument passing and catching. I just dont understand the construct.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what the line `Player.initPlayer = function(name, health, force){......}` is doing is declaring the function method initPlayer() for each Player object that will be created.

It is (mostly) the same as saying

`var Player = {
     initPlayer: function(params) {function here}
}`

except it is declared as part of the constructor function for Player, so each Player object created using the new keyword will have access to it.

If this syntax is not clear to you, read up on constructor functions and the different way to declare and create objects in JS. [Here is a good place to start.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)